# How to permanently disable XON/XOFF settings for stty?

Tags: linux, console, serial-port, stty

I am working on an Embedded device with a serial console. I have observed that the console hangs suddenly and nothings seems to respond. The same cable when connected to another device works fine. After a lot of digging, I came to know about the XON/XOFF flags that are responsible for this. Some how '^S' character was entered on the console and it freezed it. After understanding this I was able to unlock console by entering '^Q'. But the console again hangs suddenly. My question is if it is possible to permanently disable XON/XOFF on the system? If so how?

Answer (score 3):

Usually (details depend on your particular system) that is done in the *getty* configuration.  The Linux Serial HOWTO is a good place to consult, i.e., where it mentions *stty* (section 11.4 in [this link](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Serial-HOWTO-11.html#ss11.4)).

*stty* will report what the serial line is set to, and can be used to update the settings.  But the programs that manage the serial line (getty, login) provide the initial settings.  Your shell initialization (`.bashrc` for instance) provides a finishing step.

Answer (score 3):

Run this command in terminal to disable it for current session/add it to .bashrc for disabling it permanently

```
stty -ixon
```